# spring 3.2 configuration tx:annotation-driven error in eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse-plugin, migration, spring-aop, spring-transactions

Trying to migrate from Spring 3.0 -> 3.2.4

using: Eclipse Juno (on 64 bit java 1.7), and STS 3.3,

Problem: Edit window in Eclipse/STS IDE shows:

> Error occurred processing XML
>   'org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils'

on the line where I am using `<tx:annotation-driven>`

Compiling the project results in a similar error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils
```

I've been struggling to find a resolution to this.  I'm assuming that it's something simple I've overlooked, but I can't for the life of me find it.

Here's what I've done so far:

- I've created the config file from scratch using Eclipse -> new file
  -> STS bean configuration.
- I've confirmed that maven has installed the appropriate jars into
  the classpath.
- I've compiled with both java versions 1.6 and 1.7
- started eclipse with -clean (in case there were any artifacts left by older project and workspace versions)
- `<tx:annotation-driven>` was added using the normal Eclipse ctrl+space
- explicitly added **spring-web** to pom.xml (Spring version 3.2 removed the required dependency, but it made no difference, in or out)
- explicitly added **spring-aop** to pom.xml

Any help or insights would be appreciated.

Here is my config-portlets.xml (prior version of this worked in Spring 3.0)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"     xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />  <!-- error here-->
</beans>
```

I have explicitly included spring-aop-3.2.4.Final in my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.sbeko</groupId>
        <artifactId>horse-accounts</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>horse-accounts Portlet</name>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <build>
            <plugins>...
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <source>1.6</source> <!-- 1.7 tried here as well -->
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
 <!-- bunch of stuff taken out for clarity..-->
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
<!--  bunch of stuff taken out for clarity..-->
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.25</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <hibernate.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate.version>
        </properties>
    </project>
```

Comment: can you use the eclipse 'dependency hierarchy' tab on the pom.xml file and check if there are any dependencies on spring that are lower than version 3.2.x?  sometimes you'll find a lower version from other dependencies (particularly from spring portlet) that may be causing some classpath issues.

Comment: I went through all spring dependencies, and generally cleaned up my pom - I deleted all references to spring except the lowest level jars.  e.g using spring-webmvc-portlet to get maven to bring in the higher level dependencies.  Couldn't find anything

Comment: what happens if you add the Spring Nature to the project?

Comment: I've had Spring Nature enabled since my previous version - beans don't show at all in the project explorer under JEE perspective - clearly showing that something is broken.  This has the feel of a conflict, but it's hard to know how to start tackling the issue.  I did try opening up a new workspace (but copied the layout) and I continued to have the same issue.  It's pointing to something deeper.

Comment: Any chance you could try creating a new Spring project using the Spring MVC template and Spring 3.2.4.  Then find the config file and just add <tx:annotation-driven> and let me know what happens - it will help me figure out if it's my set-up or if it's something wider.

Comment: yeah - can't seem to replicate - i pulled down the latest Spring MVC template, updated the version to 3.2.4.RELEASE, added spring-tx and the annotation, `mvn clean install` and no problems, all clean.  i even c&p'd your pom and it came up clean.  you may want to run your maven from the command line and see what you come up with - eclipse might be playing funny-buggers in the middle here

Comment: open namespace tab for your spring configuration file, and check `tx` namespace.

Comment: @incomplete-co.de - - apologies for the delay, I had to step away for a while.  Many thanks for trying to replicate, at least I now know that it's my setup.  I know Eclipse is a memory hog, and I'm living on the edge of available memory, so when I go slightly past the available memory and my PC starts to page swap, then I suspect that Eclipse gets tired of waiting and starts to do things internally to show that it's upset.  This problem maybe the embodyment of one of those artifacts.

Comment: I think the answer to problems like mine is: go away overnight, leave the computer on to fix itself.  I came back, Eclipse misbehaved with the test workspace I was using, I changed back to my project workspace and, lo and behold, <tx:annotation-driven> tag had an AOP marker against it - I have absolutely no idea why - it was a frustrating weekend, where no matter what I did, it just exhibited the same problem.  Thanks, any way, for your help

Answer (score -1):

Incomprehensible glitch with Eclipse/Java/PC.  Only answer I have is: Leave the computer on overnight without touching it and it'll fix itself.  Maybe, rebooting after taking the battery out would result in the same.

I can only suspect that some garbage collection happened, which cleared up a corruption in Java and/or Eclipse.